# Why does an object field lose its array nature

Tags: php, arrays

I'm hitting a wall in PHP and could use your help.

```
# php -v
PHP 5.3.2 (cli) (built: Jun  4 2010 19:29:54) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v3.3.20, Copyright (c) 2002-2010, by ionCube Ltd.
```

I have the following code:

```
$forwards  = $xmlapi->api2_query($account, "Email", "listforwards");
var_dump($forwards);
$mailboxes = $xmlapi->api2_query($account, "Email", "listpops");
var_dump($mailboxes);
$emails    = array();
if($mailboxes->event->result != 1) {
    wp_die( __('Not able to fetch full NN email list: '.$mailboxes->event->reason));
}
elseif($forwards->event->result != 1) {
    wp_die( __('Not able to fetch full NN email list: '.$forwards->event->reason));
}
else {
    $extract_forward_emails = create_function('$f','return $f->dest;');
    $extract_mailbox_emails = create_function('$f','return $f->email;');

    $emails = array_merge(
        array_map($extract_mailbox_emails, $mailboxes->data),
        array_map($extract_forward_emails, $forwards->data)
    );
}
```

It returns the following:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#121 (5) {
  ["apiversion"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["data"]=>
  array(60) {
    [0]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#182 (6) {
      ["dest"]=>
      string(17) "xxxxxxx"
      ["forward"]=>
      string(20) "xxxxxxx"
      ["html_dest"]=>
      string(17) "xxxxxxx"
      ["html_forward"]=>
      string(20) "xxxxxxx"
      ["uri_dest"]=>
      string(19) "xxxxxxx"
      ["uri_forward"]=>
      string(22) "adam.brisk%40gmail.com"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#181 (6) {...}
    ...
  }
  ["event"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#122 (1) {
    ["result"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  ["func"]=>
  string(12) "listforwards"
  ["module"]=>
  string(5) "Email"
}
object(SimpleXMLElement)#122 (5) {
  ["apiversion"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["data"]=>
  array(28) {
    [0]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#151 (2) {
      ["email"]=>
      string(19) "xxxxxxx"
      ["login"]=>
      string(19) "xxxxxxx"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#181 (2) {...}
    ...
  }
  ["event"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#123 (1) {
    ["result"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  ["func"]=>
  string(8) "listpops"
  ["module"]=>
  string(5) "Email"
}


Warning:  array_map() [function.array-map]: Argument #2 should be an array in xxxxxx on line 61

Warning:  array_map() [function.array-map]: Argument #2 should be an array in xxxxxx on line 62

Warning:  array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #1 is not an array in xxxxxx on line 63
```

Somehow, the `data` fields seem to have lost their Array nature. I can't figure out why this is... can anyone point me in the right direction here, please?

## Update

Even stranger. The following code:

```
$forwards = $xmlapi->api2_query($account, "Email", "listforwards");
print "Result: ".$forwards->event->result;
print "\n";
var_dump($forwards->data);
foreach ($forwards->data as $forward) {
  print $forward->dest."\n";
}
print "\nCompleted\n";
```

Returns

```
Result: 1
object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (6) {
  ["dest"]=>
  string(17) "xxxxxx"
  ["forward"]=>
  string(20) "xxxxxx"
  ["html_dest"]=>
  string(17) "xxxxxx"
  ["html_forward"]=>
  string(20) "xxxxxx"
  ["uri_dest"]=>
  string(19) "xxxxxx"
  ["uri_forward"]=>
  string(22) "xxxxxx"
}
xxxxxx
yyyyyy
.
.
.
zzzzzz

Completed
```

So, I can run `foreach` against it, but if I dump it, I only get the first element... is this normal?

Comment: What do you mean "lost"? Where are the arrays?

Comment: @Tom `["data"] => array(60) { [0]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#182 …`

Comment: Throwing a random half-line of code at me isn't particularly helpful.

Comment: @Tom That's the array you asked for in the var_dumped object.

Comment: @deceze: Right, so `data` is an array. How is that "lost its array nature"?

Comment: @Tom Because `array_map` later complains that it's not an array. It's at the end of the dump.

Comment: @deceze: Ah! I've got you now. Blimey was that difficult to parse. Reducing your code to a small, simple testcase would make this easier to spot! [edit: er, the OP, that is]

Comment: @Tomalak: noted. I think the example after the Update achieves that. Once again, we have an example of inconsistent 'array' behaviour coming from `->data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SimpleXML uses a lot of [magic](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) overloading. In some cases, this is not entirely transparent to PHP. For example, if an object implements the [`Traversable`](http://www.php.net/Traversable) interface, it's traversable using `foreach`, but does not in any other respect behave like an array. I don't know the exact implementation of the SimpleXMLElement in this case, but I'm sure you're bumping up against something like this.

For example, `SimpleXMLElement::children` cites this as a usage example:

```
foreach ($xml->children() as $second_gen)
```

while the method signature is

```
public SimpleXMLElement SimpleXMLElement::children ([ string $ns [, bool $is_prefix = false ]] )
```

with this note:

> SimpleXML has made a rule of adding iterative properties to most methods. They cannot be viewed using `var_dump()` or anything else which can examine objects.

So, `->data` is not actually an array. It just behaves like one under certain circumstances and poses as one for simplicity. In fact, it's not even a real property of the object, but something returned via `__get`.

Comment: OK, that makes some sense, but leaves me with this open question: `var_dump` indicates that the `data` field is an array. Is this some erroneous duck typing at work?

Comment: Here we go: http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php... after Example #4: "Properties ($xml->movie in previous example) are not arrays. They are iterable and accessible objects."

Comment: @Dancrumb Exactly, "iterable and accessible ***objects***." I think the SimpleXML extension it faking the values output in `var_dump`. The object most certainly does not have a "real" attribute `data`, the data for this attribute is created on the fly whenever requested. It's actually an object that implements the ArrayAccess and Traversable interfaces. Since SimpleXML is a built-in extension, it can probably fake more data than a normal object could.